# How can I fix this code so that when I press the profile icon it will redirect the user to the different ProfileView? (using SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui

I want to create a nice Nav bar and in it I would like to have a button with profile which after being tapped redirects the user to its profile.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewHomeView: View {
    @State var show = false
    @State var showProfile = false
    @State var viewState = CGSize.zero
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State var search = false
    @Binding var showIcon: Bool
     
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
                
            ProfileIconView(showProfile: $showProfile)
                .blur(radius: show ? 20 : 0)
                .opacity(search ? 0 : 1)
                .offset(y: showProfile ? 900 : 0)
            
            Text("Your sets")
                .offset(y: -100)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.system(size: 30))
            
            
            NewSetView()
                .offset(x: viewState.width, y: viewState.height )
                .animation(.spring(response: 0.3, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0))
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.show.toggle()
                }
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture().onChanged { value in
                        self.viewState = value.translation
                        self.show = true
                    }
                        .onEnded { value in
                            self.viewState = .zero
                            self.show = false
                        }
                )
               
        }
    }
}


struct NewHomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewHomeView(showIcon: .constant(false))
    }
}

struct NewSetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
           
            HStack {
            
                VStack {
                    
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 30)
                
                }
                
                .frame(width: 250, height: 180)
                .background(.gray)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .shadow(radius: 20)
                .offset(y: 50)
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct ProfileIconView: View {
    @Binding var showProfile: Bool
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                Text("Flashy")
                    .font(.system(.title))
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Button(action: {
                                    showProfile.toggle()
                                }) {
                                    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                                }
                            }
            .frame(width: 400)
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

let screen = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

I think the main problem is in the ProfileIconView and with @Binding showProfile.
For now I have my profileIconView in the top of the screen, but when the profile icon is tapped, it disappears:

[Image after profile icon was tapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzSN3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I little bit reproduced your code. Here is an example of how you can solve your problem:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showProfile = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                if showProfile {
                    ProfileView()
                } else {
                    HomeView(showProfile: $showProfile)
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                if showProfile {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Button(action: {
                            showProfile = false
                        }) {
                            Text("Back")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        Text("Your Profile")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                } else {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                        Text("Flashy")
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                    }
                    
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        Button(action: {
                            showProfile = true
                        }) {
                            Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    @Binding var showProfile: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HomeViewTitle()
            
            HomeViewSet()
        }
    }
}

struct HomeViewTitle: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Your sets")
            .font(.system(size: 30))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
    }
}

struct HomeViewSet: View {
    @State private var viewState: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 30)
                
            }
            .frame(width: 250, height: 180)
            .background(.gray)
            .cornerRadius(20)
            .shadow(radius: 20)
            .offset(y: 50)
        }
        .offset(x: viewState.width, y: viewState.height)
        .animation(.spring(response: 0.3, dampingFraction: 0.6, blendDuration: 0), value: viewState)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { value in
                    viewState = value.translation
                }
                .onEnded { value in
                    viewState = .zero
                }
        )
    }
}

struct ProfileView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "globe")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
        
        Text("Profile View Content")
    }
}
```